# File Creation fail depending on Uri

Tags: android, file, uri, google-photos

I am trying to create `File` from Uri comes from an android gallery so that I can upload it to the server.

```
File file = FileUtils.getFile(getContext(), image_uri);
```

But depending on image URI, it works or it doesn't work.(file return null)

This works.

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F104/ORIGINAL/NONE/1326719792
```

This doesn't

```
content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/0/1/mediakey%3A%2Flocal%253A38c415af-815a-4043-b3b3-29c7afb76439/ORIGINAL/NONE/2063753810
```

Only diffrence between two is first one is photo that was taken by device, the other is photo from GOOGLE CLOUD photo that automatically downloaded to gallery.

Is anyone have heard of this wierd behavior?

EDIT

**FileUtils.getFile**

```
public static File getFile(Context context, Uri uri) {
    if (uri != null) {
        String path = getPath(context, uri);
        if (path != null && isLocal(path)) {
            return new File(path);
        }
    }
    return null;
}


public static boolean isLocal(String url) {
    if (url != null && !url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://")) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the implementation of `FileUtils.getFile()`? That is not in the Android SDK.

Comment: Whatever `getPath()` is, it is guaranteed to be wrong.

Comment: Could you explain? What am I missing?

Comment: See the duplicates. A `Uri` does not have to point to anything on the filesystem, let alone something that you can access. In particular, on Android 10+, you do not have access to other apps' file content. So, use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`.

Comment: Thanks. for the inputs.